# Display the loading progress of my resources in my canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm facing  a problem with canvas. No errors is returned. I'm trying to make a loader, that load every ressources like pictures, sounds, videos, etc, before the start of application. The loader must draw the number of ressourses loaded dynamically.
But at this moment, my loader has the result to freeze the browser until it draws the total of ressources loaded.

Tell me if i'm not clear :)
This is the code :

```
function SimpleLoader(){
    var ressources ;
    var canvas;
    var ctx; 

    this.getRessources = function(){
        return ressources;
    };

    this.setAllRessources = function(newRessources){
        ressources = newRessources;
    };

    this.getCanvas = function(){
        return canvas;
    };

    this.setCanvas = function(newCanvas){
        canvas = newCanvas;
    };

    this.getCtx = function(){
        return ctx;
    };

    this.setCtx = function(newCtx){
        ctx = newCtx;
    };
};

SimpleLoader.prototype.init = function (ressources, canvas, ctx){
    this.setAllRessources(ressources);
    this.setCanvas(canvas);
    this.setCtx(ctx);
};

SimpleLoader.prototype.draw = function (){
    var that = this;
    this.getCtx().clearRect(0, 0, this.getCanvas().width, this.getCanvas().height);
    this.getCtx().fillStyle = "black";
    this.getCtx().fillRect(0,0,this.getCanvas().width, this.getCanvas().height)
    for(var i = 0; i < this.getRessources().length; i++){
        var data = this.getRessources()[i];
        if(data instanceof Picture){
            var drawLoader = function(nbLoad){
                that.getCtx().clearRect(0, 0, that.getCanvas().width, that.getCanvas().height);
                that.getCtx().fillStyle = "black";
                that.getCtx().fillRect(0,0, that.getCanvas().width, that.getCanvas().height);
                that.getCtx().fillStyle = "white";
                that.getCtx().fillText("Chargement en cours ... " + Number(nbLoad) +"/"+ Number(100), that.getCanvas().width/2, 100 );
            }
            data.img = new Image();
            data.img.src = data.src;
            data.img.onload = drawLoader(Number(i)+1); //Update loader to reflect picture loading progress
        } else if(data instanceof Animation){
            /* Load animation */
        } else if(data instanceof Video){
            /* Load video */
        } else if(data instanceof Sound){
            /* Load sound */
        }else {

        }
    }
};
```

So with this code, all resources are loaded, but i want to display the progress of loading. Some idea of what i missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "busy-looping" in the loader so the browser doesn't get a chance to redraw/update canvas.

You can implement a `setTimeout(getNext, 0)` or put the draw function outside polling current status in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop instead. I would recommend the former in this case.

In pseudo code, this is one way to get it working:

```
//Global:
    currentItem = 0
    total = numberOfItems

//The loop:
    function getNextItem() {
        getItem(currentItem++);
        drawProgressToCanvas();

        if (currentItem < total)
            setTimeout(getNextItem(), 0);
        else
            isReady();
    }
    getNextItem(); //start the loader
```

Adopt as needed.

The `setTimeout` with a value of 0 will cue up a call next time there is time available (ie. after a redraw, empty event stack etc.). `isReady()` here is just one way to get to the next step when everything is loaded. (If you notice any problems using 0, try to use for example 16 instead.)

Using `requestAnimationFrame` is a more low-level and efficient way of doing it. Not all browsers support it at the moment, but there are poly-fills that will get you around that - For this kind of usage it is not so important, but just so you are aware of this option as well (in case you didn't already).